# How to find a co-working space in Lille as a tourist?

Tags: work, lille

In a few weeks time, I'm hopefully going to be spending a few days in and around Lille, some working, some holiday. For the working part, I'd need somewhere to go in the day, ideally some sort of co-working space or similar.

In Paris, there's an excellent co-working space [La Cantine](http://lacantine.org/) (as mentioned in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18920/how-to-find-coworker-space-in-berlin-as-a-tourist)). Regus have [an office by the station](http://www.regus.co.uk/locations/office-space/lille-europe) which includes a [business lounge](http://www.regus.co.uk/locations/business-lounge/lille-europe), which in theory ought to be all I need. Unfortunately, the time I tried going there, it was very noisy with lots of people having meetings there (which I've not really found elsewhere), and the wifi was so bad you longed for when an [IDBus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10289/how-do-eurolines-compare-to-idbus-for-the-london-paris-route) would park outside so you could use theirs...

Are there any good co-working spaces that'd welcome a visiting tourist for half a day or a day? (Googling found places with a 1+week minimum commitment, which aren't really suitable for me as a tourist just wanting something like half a day or a day). Or failing that, are there any good places ([cafes/libraries/etc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20402/26)) I could look at going to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the website of La Cantine in Paris, I found [a map of coworking places](http://coworkinginitiatives.com/) in France. There happen to be at least 2 having a website in Lille. Both have an open space and coffee room with at least one meeting room.

[La Coroutine](http://www.lacoroutine.org/#espace) has [offers for short stay](http://wiki.lacoroutine.org/#tarifs), 2 euros per hour up to 10 euros per day.

[Co-factory](http://co-factory.fr/coworking/coworking-lille.html) only targets regular coming people apparently, [starting at 49 euros for 4 days](http://co-factory.fr/images/tarif%20du%20coworking%20nomade.pdf), but they offer a one-day trial if you email them.

Otherwise, you still have the [city public libraries](http://www.bm-lille.fr/index.php?id=125).

Comment: [La Coroutine](http://www.lacoroutine.org/#espace) turned out to be just what I was after!

Answer (score 6):

This is an old topic, but maybe it can be useful to someone else: You will find a “coffice” near Rihour Station : Helmut & Raoul.
This is similar to a co-working space, but you don't need to be a member nor to book in advance and you can come for 1 hour, 1 day… as you want.